# returning int& in function with static int

Tags: c++, function, reference, static

Suppose I hae to following:

```
int &f() {
static int x = 0;
return x;
}
void main() { f() = 5; }
```

I realize that this function returns a reference to an integer
(I have tried to use this [Function returning int&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496805/function-returning-int)).

Does it mean that x will be equal to 5 in this case?

I do not really realize what `f() = 5`in that...

In addition, what change could it make If would omit 'static' above?.
I know  that static int is an integer which exist actually before the program exists, but I am not sure it helps me to understand what change would happen.

I am trying to find out the answers for that with using debugger.

Comment: Have you tried figuring out the answer to your own question, by yourself, simply by using a debugger to run this program, one statement at a time, and verifying whether or not your hypothesis is correct, that `x` will be set to 5? Your debugger should be able to easily tell you this, in just a few seconds. This will be actually an excellent way for you to learn how to use a debugger. Being able to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, and you can use this as an opportunity to get a jump start on learning this valuable skill.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that x will be equal to 5 in this case?

Yes. After an integer has been assigned a value, it will be equal to that value.

> what change could it make If would omit 'static' above?

Depends on how you intend the program to behave. Only removing `static` would make the program to have undefined behaviour, so that would not be a good idea. One possible change would be to remove the entire function declaration, and the call to it.